# Unable to update AD fields with Set-ADUser

Tags: csv, powershell, active-directory

I am attempting to update ActiveDirectory with information using a CSV file and a PowerShell script.

```
foreach ($user in $users) {            
    Get-ADUser -Identity $user.SamAccountName -Properties *         
}
```

returns the values for the users in my CSV file and I can see the property names and values in ActiveDirectory.

And this code:

```
$users = Import-Csv -Path C:\ADTest\DirectoryExport2.csv                       
foreach ($user in $users) {            
    #Search and Update existing attributes            
    Get-ADUser -Identity $user.samaccountname |
        Set-ADUser -Replace @{GivenName=$user.givenName}
```

allows me to replace the `GivenName` value in ActiveDirectory with the value in my CSV.  I have 8 more values that I need to update and when I try to add these to the code it does not work.

These are the 2 code attempts I have tried:

```
$users = Import-Csv -Path C:\ADTest\DirectoryExport2.csv                      
foreach ($user in $users) {            
    #Search and Update existing attributes            
    Get-ADUser -Identity $user.samaccountname |
        Set-ADUser -Replace @{GivenName=$user.givenName}
    Get-ADUser -Identity $user.samaccountname |
        Set-ADUser -Replace @{Surname=$user.sn}
}
```

I have tried this also:

```
$users = Import-Csv -Path C:\ADTest\DirectoryExport2.csv                      
foreach ($user in $users) {            
    #Search and Update existing attributes            
    Get-ADUser -Identity $user.samaccountname |
        Set-ADUser -Replace @{GivenName=$user.givenName;Surname=$user.sn}
}
```

But I get this same error message for both attempts:

This is the Error message:

```
Set-ADUser : The specified directory service attribute or value does not exist
Parameter name: Surname
At line:5 char:55
+ Get-ADUser -Identity $user.samaccountname | Set-ADUser <<<<  -replace @{Surname=$user.sn}
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (CN=Test1User1,O...-sheriff,DC=net:ADUser) [Set-ADUser], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : The specified directory service attribute or value does not exist
Parameter name: Surname,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADUser
```

The parameter name `Surname` does exist in ActiveDirectory because I can see it when I run the first code above below is the results of that query.  As you can see they are blank.

```
State                              : 
StreetAddress                      : 
Surname                            : 
Title                              :
```

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Surname does not exist in AD. It's sn. The mapping of names between PowerShell cmdlets and AD is not the same. PowerShell is presenting friendly names in some cases. You only need to use `-Replace` when the parameter does not exist. For example: `set-aduser -Surname $user.sn -GivenName $user.givenName` should work. Technet has more info https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ee617215.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your help it was very good. This is what I ended up with for my finale code.  I had to repeat this code for each item I update in AD put it works.  Also had to stay with the -Surname the -sa threw an error. Again thank you

```
IF([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($user.sn))
{        
    Set-ADUser -Identity $user.samaccountname -Surname $null

}else{

    Set-ADUser -Identity $user.samaccountname -Surname $user.sn
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[TechNet for `Set-ADUser`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ee617215.aspx) has part of the answers here. The misconception is thinking that there is a *direct* correlation between the user properties of the active directory cmdlets in PowerShell and Active Directory.

Look at the parameter list for `Set-ADUser`. The examples you show are already covered and you do not need to use `-Replace`. `Set-ADUser` also has an `-Identity` parameter so you can skip one cmdlet.

```
Set-ADUser -Identity $user.samaccountname -Surname $user.sn -GivenName $user.givenName
```

Since you are working based of a csv you should be careful about users that potentially no longer exist or typos.

When one of the builtin parameters does not have the property you want is where `-Replace` will come in handy. You need to understand that the hashtable you feed into there uses the LDAP properties of AD.

If you look at the [MSDN for Surname](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679872(v=vs.85).aspx) you will see the Ldap-Display-Name as `sn`. That is why you got an error as surname does not exist in AD

Comment: It didn't look like you wanted to post an answer, so I posted a community wiki answer. Should I delete it? No need to have the same answer twice.

Comment: I'll just delete mine. I didn't want to answer as it was a simple one. Though someone would have said something but it had been 30 minutes and I saw no activity. I just wanted it done.

Comment: Nah, take the credit. You were the first one to respond with a solution anyway. Should've just posted an answer instead of commenting, though.