# Modify exchange attribute in Active Directory using set-aduser

Tags: powershell, active-directory, exchange-server

I planned to update the exchange attribute in Active Directory The exchange attributes will included `mDBUseDefaults`,`homeMDB`,`msExchHomeServerName` and `mailNickname` .

1. May I know whether the powershell `set-aduser` command is allowed to update those values ?
2. If no, what is the recommended way to update ?
3. If yes, what are those attribute name in powershell ?

I tried in my powershell and I received back the following error

```
Set-ADUser : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'MSExchHomeServerName'.
Set-ADUser : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'homeMDB'.
Set-ADUser : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'mailNickname'.
```

These are my powershell command

```
 Set-ADUser 1000 -AccountExpirationDate $Time
 Set-ADUser 1000 -MSExchHomeServerName $exch
 Set-ADUser 1000 -homeMDB $db
 Set-ADUser 1000 -mailNickname $mailNickName
```

`$Time`,`$exch`,`$db` and `$mailNickName` are containing the valid and correct value for update. I tested I can query the exchange attribute based on user `1000` in Active Directory, I can set the account expire date for user `1000` Active Directory but I am know sure how to reset the exchange attribute. I searched a lot of online resources but none of them help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/set-aduser?view=windowsserver2019-ps)

> The Set-ADUser cmdlet modifies the properties of an Active Directory user. You can modify commonly used property values by using the cmdlet parameters. You can set property values that are not associated with cmdlet parameters by using the Add, Remove, Replace, and Clear parameters.

Examples:

```
Set-ADUser -Identity GlenJohn -Replace @{title="director";mail="glenjohn@fabrikam.com"}

Set-ADuser -identity GlenJohn -Replace @{mailnickname="$($mynewmailnickname)"
```

Note that for supportability reasons Exchange commandlets should be used to modify Exchange attributes.

*Edit*: related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35139436/unable-to-update-ad-fields-with-set-aduser)